# Mathematical names of the sets and elements of standard computer numbers

Tags: computer-science, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

In standard computer arithmetic, there are two sets of numbers.

- N-bit unsigned numbers. The elements are natural numbers in $(0, 2^N]$. Arithmetic operations is defined as for the natural numbers except all operations are modulo $2^N$.
- N-bit signed numbers. The elements are integers in $(-2^{N-1}, 2^{N-1}]$. Arithmetic operations rules for complement [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements) [[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement) arithmetic are more complex than a simple modulo.

  - For example, $-2^{N-1} = --2^{N-1} = 2^{N-1}-1 + 1$.

**What are these two sets (and their elements) called?**

I understand these sets of numbers and their corresponding operational semantics completely, but I want to know how these sets and their elements are correctly *named* from a mathematical perspective. For example: the generic concept "unsigned numbers" and their arithmetic operations is more correctly (or usually) called something like "the field of natural numbers".

Comment: Aren't unsigned numbers the the integers (avoiding the question of whether $0$ is a natural) in $[0,2^N)$?  I thought $0$ was allowed and the largest was $2^N-1$.  Similarly for signed, though it depends on whether you use sign-magnitude, two's complement or one's complement.  In two's complement you can express $-2^{N-1}$, but not $2^{N-1}$.  You seem interested in these details.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell from your description (I don't know much about CS), these structures are both $\mathbb{Z}/2^N\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. the integers modulo $2^N$, only using different sets of [representatives](http://www.math.csusb.edu/notes/rel/node3.html). The elements of this structure could be referred to as simply "integers modulo $2^N$", or perhaps "[equivalance classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of $\mathbb{Z}$ modulo $2^N$".

When we talk about [the integers mod $n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Ring_of_congruence_classes), we usually use the symbols $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ to refer to the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, but the elements are, properly, equivalence classes of $\sim$ where $a\sim b$ when $n$ divides $a-b$. There's no mathematical reason for using the representatives $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$; we could just as easily use $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, or $\{-n+1,-n+2,\ldots,0\}$, or $\{5n,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, etc. and different choices don't change the structure. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement#Why_it_works) seems to be where they explain it in the article.

By the way, $\mathbb{Z}/2^N\mathbb{Z}$ is not finite field if $N\neq 1$, and the [natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) do not form a [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29). The proper name for the structures $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) (this ring is a field if and only if $n$ is a prime number), and the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ form a [semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup). The [integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) $\mathbb{Z}$ are a ring, however.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my misuse of "field" and the clarification of "rings".

Comment: I see your point about equivalence classes: the elements of the sets are isomorphic to each other. But, the "sets + operations we can do on them" differ, as well as the way we use them an interpret them. For instance, the operation "abs" is not isomorphic between the two sets. I was hoping that the "sets + the valid operations defined on them" with the commonly-understood semantics of computer arithmetic mapped to some well-known concept name in mathematics.

Comment: It is more than the structures being isomorphic; the structures are *identical* (this can be a subtle point). As I understand it, the only difference is in how the computer is instructed to *represent* the equivalence classes internally. Here is an analogy: the algorithm we use to add integers might look different depending on whether we're using base 10 or base 2, but the integers are still the integers; only our representation of them changed. Anything we can do with integers in base 10 we can also do in base 2.

Comment: Also, there is no well-defined "absolute value" function on the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ without first making an (arbitrary) choice of representatives. This should not be interpreted as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ being a different structure when we choose different representatives; rather, as an indication that "absolute value" is not a useful concept to apply to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (well, it is, but in a [much different way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Analytic_approach)).

Comment: Yes and no. Depending on flags set for overflow and underflow they may not be a ring. And there is additional structure which varies between them - in particular, there is an almost-total "division" function which is usually $x/y = \lfloor \frac{x}{y} \rfloor$ or sometimes $x/y = \mathop{\mathrm{sgn}}(\frac{x}{y}) \lfloor | \frac{x}{y} | \rfloor$ and this then depends on the particular representative values.